# MVC4 Current Link?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home")</li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("IT", "IT", "Home")
            <ul>//Dropdown
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Data Backup", "DataBackup", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

For example this is my menu my css class is "selected" for active link.. I want to use it at the easiest way. Can any one help me for MVC4.. I have looked some solutions but don't have much knowledge to use it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ul class="@{booleanForThisIsSelected ? "selected" : "";}">//Dropdown
```

Comment: Can you specify it more.. Plz..                                  <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu"> 
<ul>
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "AboutUs", "Home")
                    <ul>  here is my code

Comment: Do you want 'selected' clsss on UL or A tag

Answer (score 0):

I use the following technique all the time, using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentLocation = window.location;
    $(function () {
        $('.menu li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href == currentLocation) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

This block at first gets the current page url, then it gets all the menu anchors and compares each one with the current page url, once it finds a match, it gives the matching anchor a special class `current` which should indicate the current page link.

Please note that the selector `$('.menu li a')` should be changes to match your own structure so it can get the menu items correctly.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. Your way is easiest one this is working on simple html links but I am working ok MVC4 the links here are Like this <li>@Html.ActionLink("CSR", "CorporateSocialResponsibility", "Home")</li>  not href here I like your way is there anything to to add class by javascript for mvc html helper..

Comment: I'm a pro in MVC, and the mentioned technique is being used inside an MVC website, @Html.ActionLink will render itself as normal anchor at the end, so this is working perfectly!!

Comment: <div id="mainmenu">
              <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu"> 
                <ul>
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "AboutUs", "Home")
                    <ul> </div></div>  This is my structure what will be in $('.menu li a')?

Comment: it should be like that `$('#myslidemenu ul li a')`

Comment: note that you must be using jQuery for my mentioned code to work. if you don't know how to use jQuery, let me know and I can help.

Comment: <!-- Javascript Start //-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/fonts/ColaborateLight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/functions.js"></script> these list are already ther

Comment: I tried now  just add the script you gave replacing with $('#myslidemenu ul li a') and add class with my own class.. I am using this in _layout.cshtml and rest the links are same that I mentioned above.. I am feeling I m almost near.. You mean to say jquery library should be used?

Comment: Above I have provide all the javascripts which are using in my project. Jquery is using in my project..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4/).

You install the nuget package.

Then you add links according to your site structure to the Mvc.Sitemap-file.
Now you should be able to use the **MenuHelperModel.cshtml**-file to define the rendering behaviour of all links in your sitemap (including currently selected ones), an example of this could look like this:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<ul id="menu">
    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) {
        string classes = node.IsCurrentNode | node.IsInCurrentPath | node.Children.Any(n => n.IsCurrentNode)
            ? "selected" : "";

        <li class="@classes">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node) 
            @if (node.Children.Any()) {
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

All you have to do now is ensure your links show up on your page, best location to put it should be your Layout-/Master-Page.

There you could for example add a call to

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap("MvcSiteMapProvider").Menu(0, true, false, 1)
```

Which renders only the first level of your sitemap.

*If you want a more verbose example using this you can take a look at my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15659394/2186023).
But keep in mind that uses the now obsolete [MvcSiteMapProvider](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider)-Package, so there is a slight syntax change inside MenuHelperModel.cshtml.*